# How can I access certain member functions through an explicit name

Tags: c++, wrapper

I want to wrap what the C++ filesystem uses to represent files and folder. It has "directory entries" which seem to be the individual items in the directory hierarchy/tree, and then "path"s, which seem to be the strings that represent the filenames/paths. I want to be able access path functions through a qualified name, as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <string>

class DirectoryEntry
{public:
    std::filesystem::directory_entry dirEntry;
    // std::filesystem::directory_entry methods
    bool exists() { return dirEntry.exists(); }
    size_t fileSize() { return dirEntry.file_size(); }
    bool isRegularFile() { return dirEntry.is_regular_file(); }
    bool isDirectory() { return dirEntry.is_directory(); }

    //std::filesystem::path methods
    bool hasExtension() { return dirEntry.path().has_extension(); }
    std::string filename() { return dirEntry.path().filename().string(); }
    std::string extension() { return dirEntry.path().extension().string(); }
};

int main()
{
    DirectoryEntry entry;

    bool b = entry.hasExtension(); 
    // I want to call something "entry.path.hasExtension()"
    // or "entry.path().hasExtension();
}
```

I thought about placing all the "path" functions into an empty "class Path" class, then including a "Path" member inside the "DirectoryEntry class. The problem with this is that the "Path" class won't have access to the std::filesystem::directory_entry::path, because it's in the DirectoryEntry class. I thought I could pass the argument into the Path class methods, but is there a simpler way?

It was suggested that I could use inheritance, but I can't see how that gives the new Path class access to the std::filesystem::path() function I need:

```
    class DirectoryEntry : public std::filesystem::directory_entry
    {public:
        typedef std::filesystem::directory_entry base_t;
    
        bool exists() { return base_t::exists(); }
        size_t fileSize() { return base_t::file_size(); }
        bool isRegularFile() { return base_t::is_regular_file(); }
        bool isDirectory() { return base_t::is_directory(); }
    
        struct Path
        {
            bool hasExtension() { return bool(); } // What do I return?
            // return (outerClassObject).path().hasExtension;
    
            std::string filename() { return std::string(); } // What do I return?
            std::string extension() { return std::string(); } // What do I return?
        } path;
    };

This doesn't work. Likewise, passing the std::filesystem::path argument to the my Path class doesn't work:

class DirectoryEntry
{private:
    typedef std::filesystem::path path_t;
    typedef std::filesystem::directory_entry base_t;
    std::filesystem::directory_entry entry;
public:
    bool exists() { return entry.exists(); }
    size_t fileSize() { return entry.file_size(); }
    bool isRegularFile() { return entry.is_regular_file(); }
    bool isDirectory() { return entry.is_directory(); }

    struct Path
    {
        bool hasExtension(const path_t& path) { return path.has_extension(); }
        std::string filename(const path_t& path) { return path.filename().string();} 
        std::string extension(const path_t& path) { return path.extension().string(); } 
    } path;
};

int main()
{
    DirectoryEntry entry;
    entry.isRegularFile();
    entry.path.extension(); // MUST BE PASSED THE std::filesystem::path ARGUMENT

}
```

It seems the answer from lubgr is the only thing that works. I have to keep another copy of std::filesystem::path, don't I?

Comment: I think I have missed something, because I think that inheriting might be the too obvious solution here. You are aware of the concept of inheritance in OOP C++, aren't you? If there is a reason (even an obvious one which only I missed) to reject that, conisder explaining your decision or the impossibility.

Comment: @Yunnosch No, there's no reason I can't inherit from std::filesystem::directory_entry. It's just I'm usually used to inheriting from my own classes, not the standard library ones. Yes, that might best.

Comment: If I turn that into an answer, would you consider it an answer? That does not mean that you accept it. Better make it an answer yourself, for completeness. If tomorrow it still seems the best option, you can even accept your own answer.

Comment: @Yunnosch yes i'd accept that ansewer, thank you

Comment: Important info by OP (from a comment on my now deleted answer): Actually I don't simple inheritance solves the problem. I think I still end up with not being able to get the std::filesystem::path member from std::filesystem::directory_entry

Comment: @Yunnosch Hi. I've added two different versions in my question, one with inheritance, I still can't get access to the std::filesystem::directory_entry::path() function

Answer (score 1):

What you might want is a nested, inner type. As nested classes in C++ don't have implicit access to their outer class, you need to pass references to data members explicitly, but that doesn't add much noise. Example:

```
class DirectoryEntry {
  public:
   std::filesystem::directory_entry dirEntry;

   // as before ...

   struct Path {
     const std::filesystem::directory_entry& dirEntry;
     bool hasExtension() { return dirEntry.path().has_extension(); }
     std::string filename() { return dirEntry.path().filename().string(); }
     std::string extension() { return dirEntry.path().extension().string(); }
   } path{dirEntry};
};
```

And usage:

```
DirectoryEntry entry;

bool b = entry.path.hasExtension();
```

Comment: This is good, you have to keep another copy of std::filesystem::directory_entry, don't you? This is the only way of accessing these functions with an explicit name, ie., entry.path.hasExtensions() instead of simply entry.path.hasExtensions()?

Comment: There is no copy involved, as the inner class has a _reference_ data member that refers to the `dirEntry` instance of the outer class.

Comment: Ah Beautfiul then. So you keep an extra reference. This is the only way to do it then...